# Update single value inside map in Firestore DB

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Collection of **Units**, each unit have many fields. One of those fields is A map called **Settings**. The settings is <String,Any>: A->true, B->false, C->"Hello" etc.
I wish to update one of them, lets say I wish to set C to "World".

My code:

```
suspend fun updateData(unitID: String): Boolean = suspendCoroutine { cont ->
    val firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()

    firestore.collection("Units").document(unitID).get().addOnCompleteListener { it1 ->
        if (it1.isSuccessful) {
            val settings = it1.result.get("Settings") as? HashMap<String, Any>
            if (settings != null) {
                settings["C"] = "World"

                val map = hashMapOf<String, Any>()
                map["Settings"] = settings
                firestore.collection("Units").document(unitID).update(map).addOnCompleteListener { it2->
                    if (it2.isSuccessful) cont.resume(true)
                    else cont.resumeWithException(it2.exception!!)
                }
            }
        }
        else cont.resumeWithException(it1.exception!!)
    }
}
```

What am I doing? I am getting the map, updating the value and setting it back.
My question, is that the correct approach, can I just set the value without reading the data first?

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot. Besides that, what's the value `unitID` inside your reference? Do you get any errors?

Comment: Yes,You can update without read any data after fetch the data.If you are passing correct UID,No issue .@Dim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it:

```
suspend fun updateData(unitID: String): Boolean = suspendCoroutine { cont ->
    val firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    val map = mapOf("Settings.C" to "World")
    firestore.collection("Units").document(unitID).update(map).addOnCompleteListener { updateData ->
        if (updateData.isSuccessful) cont.resume(true)
        else cont.resume(false)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

its fine to update the data without reading it. it would save your read query limit. so don't have to do that unless there is a actual need to do.

**Suggestion:**

Don't name it1, it2 like that. use meaning full names.